# Why did maximum HP drop after leveling up?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Upon leveling from 8 -> 9, the maximum health of everyone in my party dropped, almost by 60 points in some cases:
[image]

Note that Karlach has 146 max hit points, although the odd thing is that the numbers don't match up in the tooltip.
[image]

After leveling up, Karlach has 80 maximum hit points. It lines up with the tooltip now, but where did those hit points go and where did they come from?

Comment: Is it possible you had some form of health boon that was then removed by levelling up?

Answer (score 7):

On a recent patch, the health point bonus from the Explorer difficulty mode was increased significantly. I changed the difficulty to Explorer and the health points lined back up (I had changed to Balanced difficulty in order to multiclass).

Comment: Yes, this was introduced in [Patch #1](https://baldursgate3.game/news/patch-1-now-live_87) (Balanced: "*Increased players' HP bonus in Explorer Mode from +50% to +100%.*") and apparently this changed in running games as well whenever difficulty levels were switched.

Comment: I was gonna ask how the heck you got that much hp in the first place, but the mode explains it :)